# How to use Win32 API ReportEvent in QT

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I am writing a Windows service in C++ using QT 5.4, the service can be run, but I would like to log some event into the system. I have searched a bit seems the Win32 API ReportEvent() suits for this.

However, most of the resource I found involved using mc.exe and rc.exe which seems to be missed in the QT environment, and the most updated Windows SDK for Windows 8.1 does not contain these tools as well.

If Visual Studio is not available for me, how can I use ReportEvent()in QT? Or is there any alternative solution for logging events?

Thanks!

Comment: The Windows SDK does include the resource and messages compilers I believe. Anyway, VS is available. Express has the tools.

Comment: You should be able to link against win32-api-dll using other compilers too, see http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msvc_and_mingw_dlls

Comment: Thanks for responding, seems that the command line tools is removed in the latest version Windows SDK. VS express should have the tools, but I am not sure if the license allow me to use it as I am working on a commercial project (from the download page, it just mentioned "may be" only). After searching a bit more, mingw contains alternative tools, windmc.exe and windres.exe to replace mc.exe and rc.exe respectively. At least I can build the service sample from MSDN now...